# Playframeowk with Java throws JPA Transaction failed. caused by: there is no started appliaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, guice

I am using Play 2.5.7 with Java and hibernate. I need make some db call and load config on application start. It keeps failing with the error in the title.
Code, application startup class:

```
public class ApplicationStart {
    @Inject
    public ApplicationStart(JPAApi jpaApi, ConfigService configService) {
        jpaApi.withTransaction(() -> {
            configService.reloadConfigs();
        });
    }
}
```

Module, configure method:

```
bind(HibernateDao.class).to(HibernateDaoImpl.class);
bind(ConfigService.class).to(ConfigServiceImpl.class);
bind(ApplicationStart.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

ConfigureServiceImpl:

```
@Override
public void reloadConfigs() {
    List<Implementation> impls = hibernateDao.executeQueryForObject(QUERY_GET_IMPLEMENTATIONS, null);
    // process and load the condig.
}
```

HibernateDaoImpl:

```
@Override
public <T> List<T> executeQueryForObject(String sql, Map<String, Object> map)
        throws PersistenceException {
    EntityManager em = JPA.em("default");
    try {
        Query query = prepareQuery(em, sql, map);
        List<T> objectList = query.getResultList();
        return objectList;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Actual error:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: JPA transaction failed
...
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JPA transaction failed
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:86)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:86)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:86)
        at play.api.Play.current(Play.scala)
        at play.Play.privateCurrent(Play.java:89)
        at play.Play.application(Play.java:22)
        at play.db.jpa.JPA.jpaApi(JPA.java:48)
        at play.db.jpa.JPA.em(JPA.java:60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using the static `JPA.em`, instead of injecting the right class. Inject it like you did in the `ApplicationStart` class and it should work

```
public class HibernateDaoImpl implements HibernateDao {

    private final JPAApi JPA_API;

    @Inject
    public HibernateDaoImpl(JPAApi api) {
        this.JPA_API = api;    
    }


    // (...)

    @Override
    public <T> List<T> executeQueryForObject(String sql, Map<String, Object> map)
            throws PersistenceException {
        EntityManager em = JPA_API.em("default");
        try {
            Query query = prepareQuery(em, sql, map);
            List<T> objectList = query.getResultList();
            return objectList;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I find play's documentation very confusing.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is a little confusing. Specially because between minor versions (ex: 2.4 and 2.5), a lot of api's can change.The best way to dela with that is to use the documentation the matches best your Play version and the right Javadoc/sources